# Simulating Camera Through Webcam in Xamarin Android Emulator

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin.android, android-emulator, webcam

I'm trying to get an emulated virtual device to use my laptop's webcam to simulate the device's camera. Based on my research, it should simply be a matter of enabling camera support and setting the back camera to "webcam()" which I have done, but it is not working. When I run my app that initiates the back camera, I notice a line in the output window: "Could not find requested camera." Here is the configuration for my virtual device:

[image: Virtual Device Configuration]

The app runs fine otherwise, I just can't get the camera to work. Note that it works on an actual device so the issue isn't with the app. My laptop's webcam works fine in other programs and I have ensured its drivers have been updated. Why can't it find the webcam?

Comment: Having a try with **Add Property** `hw.camera` ,and setting as `yes`.

Comment: You can see in the screenshot that I have done that.

Comment: Do you have a virtual camera installed, generally can not directly call the camera of the computer, it is recommended to install this virtual camera to try.https://manycam.com/

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm stuck at the same point. Thanks,